# How to get Attributes of html DOM childNodes in Angular2

Tags: javascript, angular

I have an html string that i received from an api. i want to pick only the url of the image or the src attribute of the image from the whole string using angular2. how should i go about it.. Any help will be much appreciated.

```
<div class="field field-name-field-image field-type-image field-label-hidden">
 <div class="field-items">
     <div class="field-item even" rel="og:image rdfs:seeAlso" resource="https://www.example.com/image/image001_42.jpg?itok=RuoKJFFA">
        <a href="/example.com">
           <img typeof="foaf:Image" src="https://www.example.com/image/image001_42.jpg?itok=RuoKJFFA" width="220" height="130" alt="title here" />
        </a>
        </div>
        </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: This is nothing you need to involve Angular. I guess creating a DocumentFragment and querying for what you need should work. `DocumentFragment` is pure browser+JS

Comment: I see.. Thanks for the idea.. Can you help me with sample codes that i can ride on

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Document/createDocumentFragment, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DocumentFragment/querySelector

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are truly getting your HTML from an API call it's likely coming in as a string, just parse the string for the `src=` and then get the value between the double quotes.

```js
let fullString = `<div class="field field-name-field-image field-type-image field-label-hidden">
 <div class="field-items">
     <div class="field-item even" rel="og:image rdfs:seeAlso" resource="https://www.example.com/image/image001_42.jpg?itok=RuoKJFFA">
        <a href="/example.com">
           <img typeof="foaf:Image" src="https://www.example.com/image/image001_42.jpg?itok=RuoKJFFA" width="220" height="130" alt="title here" />
        </a>
        </div>
        </div>
        </div>`;
        // get the start of the src
let srcStart = fullString.indexOf('src="');

// get the end of the src by starting at it's position + the number of chars
let srcEnd = (fullString.indexOf('"', srcStart + 5));

let srcUrl = fullString.substring(srcStart, srcEnd);

console.log('URL', srcUrl);
```

If you really need it to be Angular2, find the element you DO have and then use [`ViewChild()`](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html#!#parent-to-view-child) to reference it:

```
@ViewChild(myObject) myObject: ElementRef
let ref = myObject.nativeElement;
```

Comment: Amazing.. Your Codes Worked.. @Dennis you genuis.Thank you very much.

Comment: No worries! can you mark my answer correct? Helps with the SO vanity ;)